# Android Development - Is it possible to convert a ListView back into an ArrayList?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, arraylist

I am having a problem with ListViews and ArrayLists.
I have an ArrayList of items. Each item has info such as ID, Title, Price etc. I also have another ArrayList of allocations. These allocations contain an "ItemId" variable - so I plan to link this to item. (Without the use of a database.)

This is how I think I will do it. First of all I will convert my ArrayList of items into a ListView using AndroidStudio. When the user clicks on a specific item on this ListView, I will run an if statement (e.g if the Id of the selected item is 2, display the allocation with that itemId)

However there is a problem with this. I can't check the Id in this if statement because my ArrayList has already been converted to a ListView, which I can not search for specific data. Can anyone help me?

Here is the code I have at the moment:

```
public class ViewItems extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.view_items_layout);
        ListAdapter itemAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Item>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Item.itemArrayList);
        ListView itemListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.itemListView);
        itemListView.setAdapter(itemAdapter);

        itemListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                String itemPicked = ????;
                IF STATEMENT GOES HERE;
            }});
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't 'convert' your `ArrayList` into a `ListView`. The `ListView` merely *uses* the `ArrayList` to show your items - the `ArrayList` is still valid.

More precise, you add your items to the `ArrayAdapter`, which uses your exact `ArrayList`. You can use:

```
itemAdapter.getItem(i);
```

---

Complete example:

```
final ArrayAdapter<Item> itemAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Item>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Item.itemArrayList);
ListView itemListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.itemListView);
itemListView.setAdapter(itemAdapter);

itemListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        Item itemPicked = itemAdapter.getItem(i);
        IF STATEMENT GOES HERE;
    }
});
```

---

Note that since you're putting instances of `Item` in your `ArrayList`, `itemAdapter.getItem(i)` will return an `Item`, not a `String`.

Comment: Hi. I tried this, however I get an error: Incompatible Types. Required: String. Found: Object

Comment: See the revised answer.

Comment: This didn't work either, however I changed "Item" to "Object" then added "extends Object" in my Item class. Is this good practice?

Comment: Ah, missed something. Change `ListAdapter` into `ArrayAdapter<Item>`, and it should work. I have edited the answer to reflect this aswell.

Answer (score 1):

Use `getItem` of your `ArrayAdapter`

```
itemAdapter.getItem (i);
```